# Flex sensor vs stretch sensor

Tags: sensors

I  want to use sensor for stretchable or bendable movements on knees, on fabric. But I am confused that which sensor is better to use and why?

Comment: This seems a bit too broad to me. Could you tell more about the application and what you want to measure about the knee movements?